# Swift. Ensure superclass method is called in the end of subclass method

Tags: swift, inheritance

Is it possible to make sure that some particular superclass' method gets called in the end of overridden subclass method?

Please consider this (and bear with me and my silly question):

```
class SubView1 : UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews() // Layout parent(UIView) subviews

        // layout my own(SubView1) subviews 

        self.notify()
    }

    func notify() {
        // post notification that view finished layout of subviews
    }
}


class SubView2 : SubView1 {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews() // Layout parent(SubView1) subviews

        // layout my own(SubView2) subviews 

        // I want that `notify()` is called at this point 
        // and not in the end of super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

It seems to me that it is not possible with simple inheritance but maybe there is some trick to make it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option is to do this:

```
class SubView2 : SubView1 {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // layout my own(SubView2) subviews 

        super.layoutSubviews() // Layout parent(SubView1) subviews
    }
}
```

Since you call `super.layoutSubviews()` at the end, the call to `notify` will happen at the end and not before you layout SubView2.

Comment: Thank you for answering. In most cases I have to rely on layout done in super before doing layout in subclass so I guess I am out of easy options.